# Designing a class the right way

Tags: javascript, oop

I have some questions about JavaScript that I need to nail down. To help, I have a simple class definiton I'm writing:

```
var dataSource = function (src, extension) {
    return {
        exists: function () {
            // function to check if the source exists (src *should* be an object
            // and extension should be a string in the format ".property.property.theSource".
            // this function will return true if src.property.property.theSource exists)
        },
        get: function () {
            // function will return the source (ex: return src.property.property.theSource)
        }
    }   
}();
```

Questions:

1) In my current understanding of JavaScript, calling dataSource() will create a new object with *its own copies* of the exists() and get() methods. Am I correct?

2) Is there a way to write this so that if I create 1,000,000 dataSource objects I only have to have one copy of each function?

3) Should I even be concerned with (2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have there is a function that returns an istance of Object, not a JS class.

You will want to check out using `DataSource.prototype`, and you should be adding properties to or modifying `this` within your constructor if you want to use this in conjunction with `new`

You should probably be doing something like this:

```
function DataSource(src, extension){
    //Make sure this behaves correctly if someone forgets to use new
    if (! this instanceof DataSource)
         return new DataSource(src,extension);
    //store the constructor arguments
    //so you can use them in the shared methods below
    this._src=src;
    this._extension=extension;
}
DataSource.prototype.exists=function(){
    //use this._src and this._extension here
    //This method will be available to all
    //objects constructed by new DataSource(...)
};
DataSource.prototype.get=function(){
    //use this._src and this._extension here
    //This method will be available to all
    //objects constructed by new DataSource(...)
};

var instance = new DataSource('a source','an extension');
```

**Edit:** *You've mentioned you would prefer 'private' variables*

Constructing closures is the only *portable* way of simulating private properties, however in my experience prefixing them with an `_` and having a convention within your organisation to not rely on `_` prefixed variables is sufficient in most situations

Comment: Don't forget the semicolons after the function assignments. In some situations, it can lead to a nasty ambiguity for the parser.

Comment: ty, always forget those, fixed

Comment: can `src` and `extension` be kept private?

Comment: no, I meant the part: "constructing closures - is the only portable way of simulating private vars...". I'll assume you'll edit that in. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[Prototype](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml) is what you'll want to use. It will be stored once and associated with all instances of the object.

Comment: can I still keep `src` and `extension` private?

Comment: @JustCallmeDrago, what you have been doing - constructing closures - is the only portable way of simulating private vars. In my experience prefixing them with an `_` and having a convention within your organisation to not rely on `_` prefixed variables is sufficient in most situations

Comment: @Toby: Ah. That's what I was looking for. If you add that distinction to your answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create that class like this to make multiple copies easily.

- Edit - Added constructor arguments.

  ```
  function DataSource(src, extension) {
      this.src = src,
      this.extension = extension,
      this.exists = function() {
          // function to check if the source exists (src *should* be an object
          // and extension should be a string in the format ".property.property.theSource".
          // this function will return true if src.property.property.theSource exists)
      },
      this.get = function() {
          // function will return the source (ex: return src.property.property.theSource)
      }
  }
  dataSource1 = new DataSource();
  dataSource2 = new DataSource();
  ```

Comment: Why did someone down vote this answer? I'm not a Javascript guru, but this looks like a perfectly legitimate option.

Comment: @tobyodavies how is this the same?. My object is being created from a class which can be prototyped down the line if needed. The way it is created in the question does not allow for the object to be prototyped later since there is no class. What am I missing?

Comment: it's the same in terms of the question - he wanted to avoid closures, the fact this works with new is irrelevant, it still uses closures and so doesn't address the thrust of the question. i agree using real classes was necessary to solve the question, but this is just change for the sake of change, it has no advantages over the original without, as you noted, further work. The further work was what the question was about, thus it does not stand on its own as an answer.

Comment: @tobyodavies How is this question about avoiding closure?

Comment: "Is there a way to write this so that if I create 1,000,000 dataSource objects I only have to have one copy of each function?" - i.e. no creating a closure for each instance. he does not ask to be compatible with `new` (which is the only way this is different from OPs code) so how is it a question about anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted class variables in return values. So as many objects you instantiate, so many instance will be created.

According to your requirement, if you separate class variables from return types and declare only once (for all) then for every instance those properties will be available. It means those variables (defined as ExampleClass.prototype=function() {} ) will work as a static variable in c/c++

Answer (score 0):

Updated for ES6 class syntax (this is another way of writing @tobyodavies's answer):

```
class DataSource {
    constructor(src, extension) {
        this._src = src; 
        this._extension = extension; 
    }
    exists() {

    }
    get() {

    }
};
var instance = new DataSource('a source','an extension');
```

There's no need to check whether or not the class was invoked with an instance of new, as this isn't possible with ES6 classes. It will come back with a `Class constructor DataSource cannot be invoked without 'new'` error.